# Accessing variable in C++ that has been wrapped in Python

Tags: boost-python

How do I access a variable in C++ that has been wrapped in Python via BoostPython method like below(in this case I want to access `y`):

```
boost::python::exec("y = x", main_namespace);
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Assume y is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Python classes, functions, variables, etc. are contained in dicts.  Since you seem to already have the `main_namespace` dict, you can just do this:

```
using namespace boost::python;

// .................................................

object y = main_namespace["y"];
std::string yString = extract<char const*>(y);
```

Comment: Could you suggest if I want to use boost::python::ptr to accomplish the task?

Comment: No, not for something this simple.  boost::python::ptr is a reference to a boost::python::object.  If you just want to get a value of a variable, just go straight for the object.